# Canvas - can't get image data

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas

I am trying to get the image data of an image drawn into a canvas in javascript, but the script below fails silently at the `ctx.getImageData()`. No error message is displayed in console.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://www.example.com/7/44/35.png"
image.width = 256;
image.heigth = 256;

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 256;
canvas.height = 256;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 256, 256);

var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 256, 256);
console.log(imageData) //this is never called, no error is displayed in console
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:
I dont think it's a CORS related problem, I am running the script on the same domain of the image source and still failling silently**

Comment: may be caused by cross-origin data not allowed.

Comment: ok yes thats probably the case, I will investigate this

Comment: I dont think it's a CORS related problem, I am running the script on the same domain of the image source and still not working. Failling silently

Comment: Are you sure it's not called? Or is it called but nothing is being logged? Try adding a message to the `console.log()`, like `console.log(imageData, "<<<< imageData")`. Also, might be due to the image not being loaded. When the `image.src` is set, the image still needs to load, so you'll need to use a callback on the `load` event before `ctx.drawImage()`.

Comment: I run the code with the image from PHP.net, I got the error of cross-origin.

Comment: try data URL for the image source. If it works, then problem solved.  there are multiple  Q & A on stackoverflow about similar situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a few tweaks to get it working:

- Use `image.crossOrigin = "anonymous"`
- Use an `image.onload` event to wait for the image to load before using `drawImage()` and `ctx.getImageData()`.

Here's an example:

```js
var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = "http://i.imgur.com/8B8ye29.jpg";
image.width = 400;
image.heigth = 400;

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

image.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 400, 400);
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 400, 400);
  console.log(imageData.height);
}
```